# Как реализован пул потоков в Java/C++?

Tags: java, c++, многопоточность

Суть пула понимаю, но конкретной реализации не нашёл. Т.е. мне интересно, каким образом пул поток может повторно использовать потоки, если те отработали с 1 задачей и принять в себя новую, но насколько мне известно поток после завершения задачи повторно быть использованным не может, т.е. повторно выполнить Thread.start() использовать нельзя, отсюда вопрос, как пул потоков экономит ресурсы на создании поток, если потоки после завершения повторно использовать нельзя и всё равно необходимо пересоздать поток, т.е. меня интересует механизм. Может я чего-то не знаю или чего-то упустил и просто не в курсе как юзать поток повторно без получения Exception. Также хотелось бы услышать мнение C++ специалистов (В С++ я не особо силён), если есть различия с Java.  Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Скачайте исходные коды boost threadspool и (и с этого лучше начать, т.к. код намного понятнее) Poco, и посмотрите на реализацию. Это лучший вариант - увидеть, как оно решается профессионалами, чей код используется миллионами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А кто вам сказал, что поток завершается?

Если упростить, то потоки в пуле крутятся бесконечно, по сути, это:

```
while (true){
   // берётся задача из очереди и выполняется
   sleep(...);
}
```

Ближе к реальности что-то такое:

```
while (!pool.isShutdown()) {
    Runnable task = pool.waitForTaskOnQueue();  // ждём задачу
    task.run();  // выполняем
}
```

Comment: Понял, в принципе я себе это так и представлял, но не думал, что всё настолько тривиально. Мне казалось, что там есть какие-то "Магические функции", о которых я не знал :))

Comment: Добавь в цикл ожидание работы на выполнение, а то кажется что он тратит ресурсы когда ждет. Что нибудь типа pthread_cond или семафоры

Comment: @Mike это само собой разумеющееся)

Comment: @BORSHEVIK фактическая реализация может и отличаться. Но одно точно - потоки там не завершаются, ибо это не имело бы смысла. Создание потока - дело довольно затратное. Поэтому проще их создать один раз и просто в ожидание ставить.

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, я вкусре, что создание потоков вещь затратная по ресурсам и времени, поэтому и задался вопросом, как реализован пул потоков, ибо в этом и был смысл пула, чтобы избежать этих затрат ресурсов и времени, но сам принцип работы я не знал, я лишь догадывался о том, что написал автор ответа, но не думал, что всё настолько просто.

Comment: Насколько я знаю в пуле потоков реализован механизм завершения потока, если тот не юзался какое-то время. Тогда уже поток пересоздать придётся, если вдруг появится задача, но экономия ресурсов на лицо при большом количестве задач

Comment: @BORSHEVIK поток грозит по большей частью лишь нагрузкой на память, в спящем состоянии он cpu не ест. Можно, правда, на основании эвристик убивать не используемые потоки в пуле. Но это экономия на спичках )

Comment: @Suvitruf Возможно вы и правы и не стоит быть насколько евреем)